# knife search node chef_environment:staging does not show node

Tags: chef-infra, knife

When I run:

```
knife show node <node_id> -a chef_environment
```

it does print:

```
chef_environment:  staging
```

but when I search for the node using:

```
knife search node chef_environment:staging
```

it does not list the node.

Could the search index be stale? What could be wrong here?

Comment: Usually the index can get 1 min to include new nodes. Sometimes it brokes. Which server are you using (enterprise chef ? hosted chef ? opens source one ?) and in wich version, as the answer/methods vary. you may try on open source 11 a `chef-server-ctl reindex`

Answer (score 0):

The call syntax might need to change (although you might be using an older client?):

```
>knife node show <node-name> -a chef_environment
>knife search "chef_environment:staging"

>chef -v
Chef Development Kit Version: 0.13.21
chef-client version: 12.9.41
berks version: 4.3.2
kitchen version: 1.7.3
```